# wrong number or types of arguments in call to get_jobtitle

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_JOBTITLE
RETURN CHARACTER
AS
job_title CHARACTER;


BEGIN

      SELECT job_title INTO job_title
      FROM hr_jobs 
      WHERE job_id=job_id;
   
    
  RETURN  job_title;

  
  
END GET_JOBTITLE;
/
   EXECUTE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (GET_JOBTITLE('IT_PROG'));
```

Trying to run execute statement but gives me an issue, looking for some help pls. PL/SQL

Comment: What have you tried ? At first sight it looks you wrote the program, tried to run it and then you posted a question because it fails. Well... you could try to figure out why it failed (it is called "debugging"), that is how you learn a software language. Did it compile successfully ? - I'm pretty sure it didn't. As long as it doesn't compile, it cannot be run.
Hints: (1) your function get_jobtitle does not have arguments (2) there is no variable job_id defined but you are using it it the where clause

Comment: It gives you an issue, probably the important thing that it helps us orient you about how to solve the issue is adding to your code the exact error message you get, not a generic "gives me an issue". Looking at the title of your post and seeing your code I can imagine that the function GET_JOBTITLE is being defined without an input parameter, it only gives you an output parameter, so in your call it doesn't know what to do with that 'IT_PROG text you are adding to the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You created a parameterless function `GET_JOBTITLE` but you call it with varchar parameter `GET_JOBTITLE('IT_PROG')`.
So either run it without a parameter:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (GET_JOBTITLE());
```

Or add varchar parameter to your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_JOBTITLE(v_job_title varchar2)
RETURN CHARACTER
```

Secondly, im not sure what you exactly wanted to do but your condition in sql query is pointless. Instead of condition `job_id=job_id` you could also write `1=1`.